# Previous await in useEffect overwriting changes in current useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, async-await

There is an input field that will update a state called `q` to whatever the user enters, and the code inside `useEffect` will do a search with `q`.

If the length of `q` is <= 2, then I need to empty the `stuff` state.

I am having an issue where the changes from `setStuff(thing)` from the previous `useEffect` render, is overwriting `setStuff([])` happening in the current `useEffect` render

```
useEffect(()=>{
   if (q.length > 2) {
      fetchSomething(q).then(thing => setStuff(thing))
   } else {
      setStuff([]);
   }
}, [q]);
```

Comment: Not an answer but try not to abuse ternary statements like this. They work best for assignment / return values. What you're doing is more readable with a plain old `if..else`

Comment: `q` state and `stuff` state are not related now?

Comment: @DevConductor I'm not sure what you mean by not related. ```q``` is just a string state that the user can set with the input field. ```stuff``` state is the result from the ```fetchSomething``` function.

Comment: Sounds like you need to debounce the `setQ()` call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that you are not canceling the previous fetch request when the `q` changes, so you might end up with a race condition where the old request finishes after the new one and overwrites the state. You can try to use an abort controller to cancel the previous request when the `q` value changes, like this:

```
const abortRef = useRef(null);

useEffect(() => {
  if (abortRef.current) {
    abortRef.current.abort();
  }

  if (q.length <= 2) {
    setStuff([]);
  } else {
    const controller = new AbortController();
    abortRef.current = controller;

    fetchSomething(q, controller.signal)
      .then(setStuff)
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(`${error.name}: ${error.message}`);
      });
  }
}, [q]);
```

You can see the whole example [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-fast-3tws5r?file=/src/App.js).

If you are using axios, you can set the request like this:

```
axios
  .get(`/api/something?q=${q}`, {
    cancelToken: controller.signal, // Pass the signal as the cancelToken
  })
  .then((response) => {
    setStuff(response.data);
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    if (error.name === "AbortError") {
      return;
    }
    console.error(error);
  });
```

Answer (score 2):

If you don't have a a system setup where you can easily cancel requests you can just ignore the response you are getting back when you no longer need it.

This is untested, but this should work just fine.

```
useEffect(()=>{
   // Create a variable to signify whether the useEffect
   // has run its clean up function.
   let isDisposed = false;

   if (q.length > 2) {  
      fetchSomething(q).then(thing => {
         // check if the useEffect clean up function has
         // run, we don't want to update state if this
         // is not the most recent (current) use effect
         if (!isDisposed) {
            setStuff(thing);
         }
      })
   }
   else {
      setStuff([]);
   }

   // Specify the clean up function.
   return () => {
      // Set the variable to signify the clean up
      // function has been run.
      isDisposed = true;
   }
}, [q]);
```